# How print some keys from a dictionary Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm experimenting with a little bit of code, this is what I want: I want to print the keys from a dictionary but only if this keys have a value more than 10. This is my code:

```
var alumnos = ["jose": 20, "leo": 56, "hadad": 8]
```

In this case only "jose" and "leo" have to be printed, because their values are more than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
for (key, value) in alumnos {
   if value > 10 {
      print(key)
   }
}
```

You can also turn it into a function like so:

```
func printKeyForValueGreaterThan10<T: Hashable>(dict: [T: Int]) {
  for (key, value) in dict {
    if value > 10 {
      print(key)
    }
  }
}
```

And call it by passing your dictionary.

```
printKeyForValueGreaterThan10(dict: alumnos)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the keys of interest using higher-level functions:

```
let keysOfValuesAboveTen = alumnos.filter {$0.1 > 10}.map {$0.0}
```

You can make a string with a separator from it like this:

```
let str = alumnos.filter {$0.1 > 10}.map {$0.0}.joinWithSeparator(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most basic way to solve this problem:

`for (stringKey, intValue) in alumnos {
     if intValue > 10 {
         print(stringKey)
     }
 }`